# How to transfer bucket from one google cloud account to another?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have two google cloud account, need to transfer **cloud storage bucket** from one google cloud account to another one.

After a bit of research, I found to use "Data Transfer".

Am able to correctly select the bucket
[image]

but when I click on transfer, how should I attach another account bucket?
[image]

Is there any easy way out?
Or I should download whole data from one bucket and then move to another?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are your authorization on the target bucket? And on the target project which host the bucket?

Comment: Have you given access to the service accounts on both buckets?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere both the bucket are of google cloud.

Comment: both of them are attached to two different service account how can I give one service account to access two different buckets in two different accounts @ralemos

Comment: I just write [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62933850/how-to-give-service-account-access-to-two-projects/62937626#62937626). Does it help you?

Answer (score -1):

Check the  source service account and grant the on target project