# How to give service account access to two projects?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

Using Google Cloud, there exists a BigQuery View table that queries two projects.

However, on the project where the view is located, we wish to run a query against it from Airflow/Composer. Currently it fails with a 403.

AFAIK it will use the default composer service account - however it doesn't have access to the 2nd project used in the sql of the view.

How do I give composer's service account access to the second project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about a service account like a user account: you have a user email that you authorize on different project and component. Exactly the same thing with the service account email.

The service account belongs to a project. An user account belongs to a domain name/organisation. No real difference at the end.

So, you can use a service account email like any user accounts:

- Grant authorization in any project
- Add it in Google Groups
- Even grant it viewer or editor role on GSuite document (Sheet, Docs, Slides,...) to allow it to access and to read/update these document!! Like any users!

**EDIT**

With Airflow, you can [defined connexions and a default connexion](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/connections#default-connections). You can use this connexion in your DAG and thus use the service account that you want.

Comment: But isn't the composer service account managed by Google? I don't see it in the IAM list.

Comment: I updated my answer. You can manage your connexion with Airflow

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to add the service account into project IAM.

Comment: But isn't the composer service account managed by Google? I don't see it in the IAM list.